# compile scala-spark file to jar file

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark, sbt

Im working on a project of frequent item sets, and I use the Algorithm FP-Growth, I depend on the version developed in Scala-Spark

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/fpm/FPGrowth.scala

I need to modify this code and recompile it to have a jar file that I can include it to Spark-shell , and call its functions in spark

the problem s that spark-shell is un interpreter , and it finds errors in this file, Ive tried Sbt with eclipse but it did not succeded .
what i need is compiler that can use the last version of scala and spark-shel libraries to compile this file to jar file.

Comment: Can you share the errors you are getting? Are you trying to include jars to spark-shell and call its functions from .scala file?

Comment: In fact, what i want is a way to compile my own class and convert it to jar file and include it to spark-shell, then call my class functions from spark shell.

Answer (score 1):

Got your question now!

All you need to do is add dependency jars(scala, java, etc.,) with respect to the machine you are going to use you own jar. Later on add the jars to spark-shell and you can use it like below,

`spark-shell --jars your_jar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

- check out Spark repository
- modify files to want to modify
- build project
- run `./dev/make-distribution.sh` script, which is inside Spark repository
- run Spark Shell from your Spark distribution

Comment: I can not modify jar files in spark repository, my question in another way how to compile my own class and include it to spark-shell

Comment: You must create your own distribution. You don't have to upload jars into Maven Central, you can read jars from local repository